# Rails 3 - Same controller for two subdomains different scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, subdomain

I want to use the same controller for 2 subdomains but with different scope.

For example (in my routes.rb):

```
constraints :subdomain => "admin" do
  resources :photos
end

constraints :subdomain => "www" do
  scope "/mystuff"
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

Now when i run "rake routes" i have both "/mystuff/photos" and "/photos".

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it ok to do this ?
2. How do i use named routes in this case? Do i have something like admin_photos_url and www_photos_url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just fine to do that... Routing in Rails is flexible for a reason (to allow for situations like this one).

However, I would change up your routes to be more like this in order to name your path helpers correctly:

```
scope :admin, :as => :admin, :constraints => { :subdomain => "admin" } do
  resources :photos
end

scope '/mystuff', :as => :mystuff, :constraints => { :subdomain => "www" } do
  resources :photos
end
```

Which will give you:

```
      admin_photos    GET    /photos(.:format)                      {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                      POST   /photos(.:format)                      {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
   new_admin_photo    GET    /photos/new(.:format)                  {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
  edit_admin_photo    GET    /photos/:id/edit(.:format)             {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
       admin_photo    GET    /photos/:id(.:format)                  {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                      PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)                  {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                      DELETE /photos/:id(.:format)                  {:subdomain=>"admin", :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
    mystuff_photos    GET    /mystuff/photos(.:format)              {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"index", :controller=>"photos"}
                      POST   /mystuff/photos(.:format)              {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"create", :controller=>"photos"}
 new_mystuff_photo    GET    /mystuff/photos/new(.:format)          {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"new", :controller=>"photos"}
edit_mystuff_photo    GET    /mystuff/photos/:id/edit(.:format)     {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"edit", :controller=>"photos"}
     mystuff_photo    GET    /mystuff/photos/:id(.:format)          {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"show", :controller=>"photos"}
                      PUT    /mystuff/photos/:id(.:format)          {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"update", :controller=>"photos"}
                      DELETE /mystuff/photos/:id(.:format)          {:subdomain=>"www", :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"photos"}
```